# SOLR: populate with data from children

Tags: indexing, solr, calculated-field

I have Products in my SOLR index. I need to create calculated fields for each product. These fields are based on product's children.
Is it possible to create such calculated fields?

For example, I have a Product with id 1, I need to add all the Detail entities, which have "parentId" field value 1. Here is a brief schema: https://www.screencast.com/t/EkNG8NpFp.
I need to have values "v1", "v3" from the example above.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you exactly mean by "create such calculated fields"...

- if you mean if you can query for Products and then for example get the average of field 'value'. Yes you can do stuff like that, look at [json facets](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/) and how you can use children docs.
- if you mean how you can add some new field to your Product doc, based on the values of the children docs, then you can probably do it with [Streaming Expressions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Streaming+Expressions). You need to use the current collection as a source, and compute the new fields, and finally add the new docs (including the new field) into a new collection